# fully standalone exe from cython

Tags: python, exe, cython, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have a python script that intended to be a fully independent exe, this can be done - as far as I reached - by the following methods:

1- use something like py2exe or pyinstaller. And their problem is quite known that the output is very large compared to anything else,, not good to have tens of MBs to only print hello world. So, I hope no one recommend using them.

2- the other is to compile it to C then take this C compile it to exe 
I have tried 2nd solution and reached good size exe using Cython

```
cython --embed my_code.py
```

This gives my_code.c . I took it to visual studio compiler to compile it :

```
cl my_code.c /I C:\python3\include /link /LIBPATH:C:\python3\libs
```

Now I have exe, but unfortunately, not stand alone at all !

1- My user defined imports should be next to it to work. ( I thought that they will be merged but this clearly didn't happen)

2- The huge problem that it still depends on python path on my computer- Lib folder

when tried on another pc (with no python) the following error came:

```
Py_Initialize fails - unable to load the file system codec
No module named encodings
```

As far as the search took me, this due to he can't find library encodings, it still looks into C:\python3\Libs ( not stand alone and still wants python installation on costumer pc)

I hope to find a solution for the above 2 problems and thank's in advance.

Comment: If you want it to not depend on your Python DLL, you need to make a static build. I'm pretty sure the demos show how to do this for Windows. Meanwhile, if you want it to call Python code out of your stdlib, you need to install the stdlib, or at least the part that you use, in some way. You don't need to use py2exe or pyinstaller for that, but if not, you have to do what it does.

Comment: Do you meant only dependence on python.dll without anything outside?

I hope you show me how to do this

Comment: The point @abarnert is making is: a Cython program will depend on the Python DLL and (some of) the Python standard library. You _cannot_ avoid this. There are ways you can bundle these with your Cython program; however, this is doing _exactly the same thing_ as Pyinstaller and will give you a file that's just as big. You should just  use Pyinstaller (it's a lot easier than doing it with Cython) and accept the large files.

Comment: isn't there a way to take this (some) and at least put it near the dll and all near my exe ?

Comment: See cx_freeze - http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html . Yes, the distributable will be large as it has to include the python interpreter. There is no way around that except not using python.